# stopping slideshow and continue after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I made this Slideshow with HTML/CSS/JS and I want to make it so that after I press an arrow key that the autoslide stops, I can just change pics manually and after 3 seconds it goes back into autoslide, but I cant figure out how this works. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

JS:

```
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 6;
var uniqueRandoms = [];

function makeUniqueRandom() {
  if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
    for (var i = imagecount; i <= total; i++) {
      uniqueRandoms.push(i);
    }
  }
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
  var val = uniqueRandoms[index];

  uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);

  return val;
}

function slide(x) {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagecount = imagecount + x;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
  ChangeText(imagecount);
}



window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
  console.log(imagescount);
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagescount + ".jpg";
  ChangeText(imagescount);
}, 3000);


function ChangeText(imgNum) {
  var allImagesAndText = {
    1: "Seltene römische Goldmünze",
    2: "Römische Funde",
    3: "Römische Wandmalerei",
    4: "Tutanchamun",
    5: "Cheops Pyramide",
    6: "Ägyptische Malerei"
  };
  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = allImagesAndText[imgNum];
}
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
}
#left_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#right_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 37%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="text1">Text</div>
  <img src="images/img1.jpg" id="img" />
  <div id="left_holder">
    <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="images/arrow_left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="right_holder">
    <img onClick="slide(1)" class="right" src="images/arrow_right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your setInterval reference to a variable, so you can stop that interval using `clearInterval()`. Now, on every call to `slide()` that you use as your arrow click handlers, you need to clear the interval at the starting of function and then set it again at the end of the function.

```
function slide(x) {
  clearInterval( sliderInterval );
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagecount = imagecount + x;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
  ChangeText(imagecount);

  sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);
}



sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);

function slideA() {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
  console.log(imagescount);
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagescount + ".jpg";
  ChangeText(imagescount);
}
```

Comment: thank you that worked for me. how do i let the left arrow on pic 1 and the right arrow on pic 6 disappear after i manually clicked from 1 to 6 or from 6 to 1?

Comment: @CuttingTheAces You can keep a counter that has the value of the current slide. Then, in every call to `slide()` you can check that counter whether this is first slide ( by 0 or 1 as you prefer ) or the last one( i.e. `if(counter==total)` ). Based on that condition you can hide show those arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Assign setInterval to a variable:

```
var silderTimerID = window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
var Image = document.getElementById('img');
imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
console.log(imagescount);
Image.src = "images/img" + imagescount + ".jpg";
ChangeText(imagescount);
}, 3000);
```

and then add keypress event handler:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
console.log(e);
// write your key condition code
clearInterval(silderTimerID)
```

});

Use `clearInterval()` to clear timer repeat.

please see demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/sxzety3e/1/